# Is it possible to change the tree view in www folder in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, tree, cordova-3, phonegap-cli

I would like to modify the tree view IN the 'www' folder of PhoneGap .

When creating the project, the automatic generation of files creates it own tree :

[image]

I would like to modify it to get this:

[image]

- The 'common' folder contains the css, js and img files
- The 'modules' folder contains all HTML pages
- The 'res' folder is the same as the original
- In the 'www' folder, there is header, index and icon

I don't use any Framework and I don't want to use one.

Is it possible to change the tree view ? If yes, how ?

**EDIT :**

I've made like @USKMobility said but i've a problem with the file load order :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it manually. Go to www folder and create required folder as you wish .

> Note : don't forgot to update file path of js or css files in
>   Index.html